# How to integrate sympy expression and latex formatting

Tags: python, sympy

Hi and thanks in advance for your help. I'm trying to get nice math formatting mixed with sympy expressions. I'm using jupyter-notebook.

I can get latex and nice sympy printing on separate lines, but can't seem to figure out a way to combine them into one line. The code below prints three lines; the third line should be the combination of the first two. Hopefully there is an elegant solution that I haven't figured out (bit of a Python noob).

```
import sympy as sym
from IPython.display import display, Math
sym.init_printing()

x = sym.symbols('x')

expr = sym.sqrt(3) * x**3
display(Math('\\frac{1}{2} ') )
display(expr)
display(Math('\\frac{1}{2} %s' %expr) )
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use string formatting, the `str` method implemented by sympy is used to convert the expression into a string.
However, the output of `str` is not intended for LaTeX output, see the [documentation of str](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorials/intro-tutorial/printing.html#str):

> To get a string form of an expression, use str(expr). This is also the form that is produced by print(expr). String forms are designed to be easy to read, **but in a form that is correct Python syntax so that it can be copied and pasted**. The str() form of an expression will usually look exactly the same as the expression as you would enter it.

So the output is intended to be valid python code:

```
>> str(expr)
'sqrt(3)*x**3'
```

To get the expression in LaTeX format, sympy provivdes the [`latex` function](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorials/intro-tutorial/printing.html#mathrm-latex).
It can be invoked as follows:

```
>> sym.latex(expr)
'\\sqrt{3} x^{3}'
```

So, simply change your last line to

```
display(Math('\\frac{1}{2} %s' %sym.latex(expr)))
```

and it should look as intended.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks! I knew it was going to be something simple that I couldn't figure out :|